# Angular : Two exclusive Toggle-Switchs not working

Tags: angular

I'd like to implement two toggle-switchs that are exclusive : if the first is on, the second should be off, and vice versa. I'm using a jquery toggle switch. The classes toggle-on and toggle-off control the behavior of each swith.
Here the main parts of my code :

[Run Code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/changuelsami/pen/ELQOWq)

```
  happy:boolean:true;
  changeAction() {
    console.log("Before ", this.happy)
    this.happy = ! this.happy;
    console.log("After ", this.happy)
  }
```

The template for the 1st switch :

```
<div class="toggle-switch" [class.toggle-on]="happy" [class.toggle-off]="!happy" (click)="changeAction()">
```

And the one for the seconde one :

```
<div class="toggle-switch" [class.toggle-on]="!happy" [class.toggle-off]="happy" (click)="changeAction()">
```

The code seems to be ok : the variable "happy" is set to "true", so the first switch is on, the second is off.

The problem is when I check an answer, the two options become ON (or OFF) and then they seem to be linked ! The debug message seems ok, but the result is not ! What's wrong with my code ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bug is in the if-else clause in your toggle switch function. This might do the trick:

```
    toggleSwitch: function(){
        $('.toggle-switch').on('click',function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('toggle-off')){
                $(this).addClass('toggle-off')
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('toggle-on')
            }
        })
```

It looks weird at first, but it will provide the functionality you needed.

Comment: Thanks :) It looks weird indeed !! I've deleted all the JS code of $(function(){ })  and now it works fine! But I don't understand why that code works fine outside angular !